# Google Maps - Custom map tiles at zoom level 1-4 then default google's map tiles at the rest zoom levels

Tags: google-maps, tiles

Is it possible to define in Google Maps API to use my own tiles at first 4 zoom levels and then when zoom goes over, map would use default Google's tiles for the rest of the zoom levels?

Answer (score 0):

Do this: when the zoom level changes, check to see what the current zoom is.  If you go from 3 to 4, then remove your layer and add the Google layer.  If you go from 4 to 3, remove the Google layer and add your own.

Comment: I am going to try it some time later. I left it with google layer for now. Thanks for the idea